# Call parent method instead of the overriden one

Tags: java, overriding

I have a class `C1`:

```
public class C1 {

    public void method() {
      //Do something
    }

    protected void anotherMethod() {
      if (something) {
          method(); 
          /*Here, I want to call the method C1.method, 
           * but C2.method is called
           */
      }
    }

}
```

and another class `C2` that `extends` it and `overrides` the `method`:

```
public class C2 extends C1 {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        if (something) {
            anotherMethod();
        } else {
            super.method();
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is described in the code comment. I can't run parent method in the parent class. What is the reason?

Comment: I don't fully follow your question, but if you want to call `C1.method()` then you should be using `super`.  In fact, you're already doing that in the `else` condition.

Comment: Plus one, on the grounds that you *can* do this in C++, so what you're asking is logical.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen his problem is the fact, that he believes that the fact that he overrides the method makes is impossible to call from C1.

Cannot reproduce. Could you please provide us [mcve]? Give us more code and show where your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly, you can't (setting aside reflective hacks).

But you could do something on the lines

```
public class C1 {
    public final void _method() /*rename to taste*/{
    }

    public void method(){
        _method();
    }
}
```

and override `method` in your derived class. If you specifically require the base class method, then call `_method()`. I think that's the nearest to writing `C1::method()` which is permissible in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your `C2` class is concerned the `anotherMethod()` is not overriden so it calls its own `method()` if `something` is true.

Override it as follows:

```
@Override
protected void anotherMethod() {
  if (something) {
      super.method(); //Here, I want to call the method `C1.method`, but `C2.method` is called
  }
}
```

to call the parent method from child's `anotherMethod()` definition.